# Count points from the entire team

Tags: php, laravel, count, one-to-many

Each user has a team and each team has several users. The respective team_id is stored in the user table.

Below I count all the points for the Auth :: User and show them to him in the View. My question is, how can I count and display the points for each team, that I can show the users their respective team with the points?

And that I can show the points of the respective teams in a list of all teams.

// --------- Userpoints --------- \

```
    $start = 200;
    $invitations = 50;
    $postp = 10;
    $commentp = 5;

    $postpup = 3;
    $postpdown = -4;
    $commentpup = 2;
    $commentpdown = -3;
    $userpostpup = 2;
    $userpostpdown = 1;
    $usercommentpup = 2;
    $usercommentpdown = 1;

    $invitedpoints = User::where('invited_from_id','=', $user->id)->count()*$invitations;
    $postpoints = $user->posts->count()*$postp;
    $commentpoints = $user->comments->count()*$commentp;

    //---get rating from users on created posts and comments---\\
    $postvotepointsup = Post::where('status', 1)->where('posts.user_id', $user->id)->upVotesAll()->count()*$postpup;
    $postvotepointsdown = Post::where('status', 1)->where('posts.user_id', $user->id)->downVotesAll()->count()*$postpdown;
    $commentvotepointsup = Comment::where('status', 1)->where('comments.user_id', $user->id)->upVotesAll()->count()*$commentpup;
    $commentvotepointsdown = Comment::where('status', 1)->where('comments.user_id', $user->id)->downVotesAll()->count()*$commentpdown;

    //---voted by user---\\
    $userpostvotepointsup = Post_activity::where('user_id','=', $user->id)->where('activity',1)->count()*$userpostpup;
    $userpostvotepointsdown = Post_activity::where('user_id','=', $user->id)->where('activity',0)->count()*$userpostpdown;
    $usercommentvotepointsup = Comment_activity::where('user_id','=', $user->id)->where('activity',1)->count()*$usercommentpup;
    $usercommentvotepointsdown = Comment_activity::where('user_id','=', $user->id)->where('activity',0)->count()*$usercommentpdown;

    $totaluserpoints =$start+$postpoints+$commentpoints+$invitedpoints+$postvotepointsup+$postvotepointsdown+$commentvotepointsup+$commentvotepointsdown+$userpostvotepointsup+$userpostvotepointsdown+$usercommentvotepointsup+$usercommentvotepointsdown;
```

Comment: this Userpoints code is a method on the User model?

Comment: No, this code is in a Controller

Comment: Why, this kind of business logic should never be in a controller. Move it to the User model, or a User repository (or something), so you can call it in other places...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this... Be aware: this is PSEUDO code, just to show a direction for a solution...

Move the points logic to the User model

```
class User extends Model {
    public function points(){
    .. your point logic ..
    }
}
```

Then in a controller, but better somewhere else: get all users from a team to retrieve a collection.

```
$collection = $team->users()->all();
```

Then you loop trough the collection while counting the user points on all individual Users...

```
$collection->sum(function(User $user){
    return $user->points();
});
```

So you will get the total for the whole team...

If you do something like this on you Team model:

```
class Team extends Model {
    public function getTotalUserPoints(){

       $allUsers = $team->users()->all();

       return $allUsers->sum(function(User $user){
             return $user->points();
       });
    }
}
```

You can get the total amount for a team by just doing:

```
$team->getTotalUserPoints()
```

And for an individual User you can get the points by calling the same logic.

```
$user->points()
```

And to get the team total via an individual user:

```
$user->team->getTotalUserpoints()
```

Again, pseudo code, just to give people an idea about where to start. This way, you have all business logic about points in one place (the user model), but you use it to get both the total and the individual scores.

Comment: Why the down vote? I don't understand. This is a perfectly normal answer...

Comment: If a post ist voted down, it is bad content and the user gets minus points

Comment: This is a logically sound answer. He showed you what two models to make your functions in and even gave you the code. All you have to do is fill in the points() function with the number of points.

Comment: Sorry, I think we misunderstood. I have not voted down your post. I thought why I count the downvotes in my function

Comment: Oooohhhh. A complete misunderstanding. I thought your comment was about my content, not your points business logic... Thanks for clearing that up!